# Jquery UI selectmenu inside modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hi i'm trying to add a selectmenu inside a modal dialog but many options are hidden and i can't click them

Here's the example

http://jsfiddle.net/4dd62ukv/1/

```
<label for="month">Month</label>
<select name="month" id="month">
<option value="0">January</option>
<option value="1">February</option>
<option value="2">March</option>
<option value="3">April</option>
<option value="4">May</option>
<option value="5">June</option>
<option value="6">July</option>
<option value="7">August</option>
<option value="8">September</option>
<option value="9">October</option>
<option value="10">November</option>
<option value="11">December</option>
</select>
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.ui-dialog {overflow: visible;}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/4dd62ukv/5/)

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to change any "z-index" or "overflow" properties to display the selectmenu right.

If you want to a selectmenu inside a dialog, first open the dialog and after the dialog is open create the selectmenu.

```
$("idOfDialog").on("dialogopen", function(e, ui){
    $('idOfSelectMenu').selectmenu();
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, but it was definitely the solution for me

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this:

```
div.ui-selectmenu-open {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 65535;
}
```

For JUI 1.11

Answer (score 2):

I found below solution. It's working for me.

```
.ui-front{z-index:0 !important; } 
.ui-selectmenu-open {z-index:9999 !important;}
```

Comment: This worked for my issue: I had a bootstrap modal with a selectmenu, and the drop down would always be behind it. I set the z-index to 1060, as the modal is defined as having a z-index of 1050. Thanks!

Comment: This one only works on first open: the dialog's z-index will be updated to whatever you set for selectmenu + 1 immediately upon closing the selectmenu.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using a property of selectmenu "appendTo".
All you need to do is provide the id/class of the division where you want the selectmenu to be visible.